# jQuery set value of select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a page and when this page is opened I want to go to the database, retrieve some data  and put this data in two select tags.
I created it and everything works good but I can't append the returned data to the select tags.

## HTML code

```
  <li>
        <label>Related Concepts</label>
        <p>
            <label>Source</label>
            <select name="source[]">
                <option>select source</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Destination</label>
            <select name="destination[]">
                <option>select destination</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </li>
```

## jQuery code

```
$('#addRelation').ready(function (){
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/Ontology/getAllConcepts/TRUE",function(data){
        var source = document.getElementsByName('source');
        var des = document.getElementsByName('destination');
        
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            source.innerHTML+="<option>"+data[i]+"</option>";
            des.innerHTML+="<option>"+data[i]+"</option>";
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i were you, I'd make the following changes:

html

```
  <li>
        <label>Related Concepts</label>
        <p>
            <label>Source</label>
            <select name="source[]" id="source">
                <option>select source</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label>Destination</label>
            <select name="destination[]"  id="destination">
                <option>select destination</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </li>
```

javascript

```
$('#addRelation').ready(function (){
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/Ontology/getAllConcepts/TRUE",function(data){
        var source = $('select#source');
        var des = $('select#destination');
        var options = '';

        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            options += "<option>"+data[i]+"</option>";
        }

        source.html( options );
        des.html( options );
    });
});
```

Since you're already using jquery, you can leverate it for dom manipulation. Also, you can speed up your selector by using an ID rather than name.

also, make sure you're accessing the data object properly.

Comment: i can't use ID for the select tags , because i will have many select tags in my page and they are created automaticly so i make there name as source[] , so i can got its values after submit

Comment: the only thing that bugs me about your selects markup is that i'm not sure what the official behavior (and selection requirement) is when your name value has trailing brackets: source[]

Comment: man it works but prints just the cs , i mean c1 doesn't print

Comment: what is the console.log( data ); output?

Comment: when the name has trailing brackets that means that i can after submit make this : $_POST['source'] , this statement returned me an array , if i have 4 selects , the array will have four values

Comment: @Kristian yes man it works as u said , really thank you i will accpet your answer

Answer (score 1):

if it's not the object, you are probably overwriting the value on each iteration:

```
var elems = $('[name="source"], [name="destination"]');

elems.empty();
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
    elems.prepend("<option>"+item+"</option>");
});
```

Comment: i alert data[0] and it prints c1 , then alert data[1] and it prints c2

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your iterate like below,

```
$('#addRelation').ready(function (){
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/Ontology/getAllConcepts/TRUE",function(data){
        var $source = $('select[name=source]');
        var $des = $('select[name=destination]');

        var options = [];
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            options.push("<option>"+data[i]+"</option>");
        }

        var optionStr = options.join('');
        $source.html(optionStr);
        $des.html(optionStr);
    });
});
```

Comment: @WilliamKinaan Try to do `console.log(data[i])` or `alert(data[i]);` and let us know what you see.

Comment: i got c1 , c2, that means it works , but why doesn't work with select ?